# VBA in Outlook not replacing string containing slashes

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the text `xx/xx/xxxx` in an Outlook template (.oft) as a placeholder for the current short form date. However, `Replace()` doesn't seem to work on it, and I can't find any evidence of needing to escape the slashes in a string for VBA.

The following does not work for me:

`.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "xx/xx/xxxx", Format(Date, "Short Date"))`

But if I swap out the placeholder with the text "PLACEHOLDER", the script works fine and the text is replaced as desired:

`.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "PLACEHOLDER", Format(Date, "Short Date"))`

Can anyone advise why this might be happening?

Comment: `xx/xx/xxxx` is getting encoded as `xx&#47xx&#47xxxx` try that in your replace statement. in HTML `/` = `&#47`

Comment: @cyboashu Just tried it out. No dice, unfortunately.

Comment: debug.print `.HTMLBody` and see what is there in place of 'xx/xx/xxxx'

Comment: @cyboashu I get the following for that line: `<p align="center" class="MsoNormal" style='text-align:center'><u><span lang="EN-CA" style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial Narrow",sans-serif;color:#7030A0;mso-ansi-language:EN-CA'>xx/xx/<span class="SpellE">xxxx</span></span></u></p>`

Comment: Hmmm... word editor adds spellE class for spelling errors. Either you change your place holder to something meaningful (dictionary complaint) such as date/month/year or change your replace string to consider that span while replacing.

Comment: On another thought, change your all x to uppercase and then check if you still get the SpellE class or it’s just a  single string?

Comment: @cyboashu Good call on the capitalizing. Replace now works, and the line is now `<p align="center" class="MsoNormal" style='text-align:center'><u><span lang="EN-CA" style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial Narrow",sans-serif;color:#7030A0;mso-ansi-language:EN-CA'>XX/XX/XXXX</span></u></p>`

Comment: @cyboashu Feel free to throw up a quick answer if you want credit and I'll mark it as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word editor adds spellE class for spelling errors (GramE for grammar). Either you change your place holder to something meaningful (dictionary complaint) such as date/month/year or change your replace string to consider that span while replacing.

Alternatively, change your all x to uppercase, that will get rid of spell check errors. and then check if you still get the SpellE class or it’s just a single string?